SVG embedded in external html page doesn't show in iframe
I want to embed an external webpage (https://flaci.com/regexp) into an html page of mine.
I did this with an iframe:
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <body>
   <p>
    Here some text
   </p>

   <iframe width="100%" height="600" src="https://flaci.com/regexp" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *; midi *; encrypted-media *"> </iframe>

  </body>
</html>

The embedding works.
When I navigate to "experiment" I can enter a regular expression like "a*b". In the original html-page a syntax diagram will be dynamically created and displayed. This doesn't work in my iframe.
Why?
I tried using object instead of iframe, but the result doesn't change.
I tried to inspect the page using mozilla's inspection tool and found, that the dimensions of the svg are different in my "iframed"-window (a lot smaller), but increasing them doesn't let the svg show.

I get a SVG with width and height set to just 2 - but when I increase those using browser dev tools, the diagram does show. Either way, I don't think there is anything you can do to fix this from your end. If the calculations that site does go wrong for some reason when it is shown inside an iframe - then they would have to fix that.
